# SSH from Windows hangs when using insert mode in vim on Dreamhost: Why?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I have SSH set up using Cygwin on Windows XP SP3 to Dreamhost. It works fine except that when I edit a file with vi and use insert mode (eg press 'i' and type in some stuff). I then try and hit escape and ZZ to save/exit and it hangs instead. My edits aren't saved and I have to kill the session (locally) and kill the vi process on Dreamhost.

This is highly annoying. It's not reliable either. Sometimes it does work.

Also, this happens with PuTTY too.

Comment: does it ever happen with the traditional :wq?

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable?

Comment: It seems to be 'cygwin'.

Comment: Try setting it to `vt100` or even better `vt220`.

Comment: I had this similar issue happen a couple of times with clients trying to use SSH with cygwin. Getting rid of cygwin solved the problem for me (I never bothered troubleshooting it past that) I've always had great luck with securecrt.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this sort of issue over SSH before, could it be related to [software flow control](http://www.nexation.com/knowledgebase/linux/putty-control-s-recovery.php)? Try hitting `Ctrl-Q` (issuing an `XON` signal) to verify.

Comment: I'm aware of the ctrl-s/strl-q thing. I'm pretty sure that's not it.